# Select all elements by id using protractor from a web page

Tags: node.js, typescript, protractor

Can we select or fetch all elements by id in a web page using protractor?
I need to list down all elements in a webpage and I tried using the below code but got the error:

> property) WebdriverBy.css: (css: string) => By
> Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
> locators.d.ts(4, 11): An argument for 'css' was not provided.

```
element.all(by.css()).each( function (el, idx) {            
    console.log(e1);           
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

As your error message indicates, you need to [provide an argument](https://www.protractortest.org/#/locators) for the CSS selector you wish to search by. For example, `by.css('.myclass')` will return all instances of `.myclass`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `element(by.id('id'))` will do the work https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.id
2. for all elements use element.all(by.id('id')) https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.all
3. Not sure what you mean you need to *list* element, assuming you need to list their text, then .getText() will do the work (only if all elems are visible) https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText
4. use `await` instead of `.then()`. I don't know which course you're taking, but it's outdated https://www.protractortest.org/#/async-await

so eventually you end up having this code

```
it('test case', async () => {
  let text = await element.all(by.id('YOUR ID HERE')).getText();
  for (let i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
    console.log(text[i]);
  }
})
```

As you see all of your questions could have been answered if you read official protractor documentation, which I highly suggest to do if you want to get comfortable with it

And lastly, ID must be unique to the page. If you're dealing with a page that has multiple elements with the same id, report it to developers

---

## P.S.

If you don't know id's in advance do this

```
it('test case', async () => {
  let allElementsWithId = $$('[id]')
  for (let i=0; i<(await allElementsWithId.count()); i++) {
    console.log(await allElementsWithId.get(i).getAttribute('id'));
  }
})
```

Comment: I do not know the IDs of the elements in advance. I need to get all the IDs available on that page. Is there a way to achieve that  ?

Comment: updating the answer. Please accept if helped @Vijay

Comment: Hi. I tried this one, but it is not listing any ids on the console. The page opens on chrome, but nothing gets listed on the console log.

Comment: there was 1 mistake I made, corrected the code below

Comment: Tried this one but again same issue. Page opens in chrome but nothing gets listed in Console Log .

Comment: then you don't have elements with id on your page, or the problem is in your framework, or you need to disable angular. Anyway, I answered your question, verified the code is working locally, for other problems, please open separate question with your observations (code, html, errors)